# If $A$ is normal, show that $A$ and $A*$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a normal matrix, show that $A$ and $A^*$ (conjugate transpose) are simultenously diagonalizable over the field of complex numbers.

I know:

- $AA^* = A^*A$
- If $A$ and $B$ are simultaneosly diagonalizable then $AB=BA$.
- If there exists an invertible P such that $P^{-1}AP$ and $P^{-1}A^*P$
  are both diagonal, then $A$ and $A^*$ are simultanously diagonalizable.
- Every normal matrix is diagonalizable.

but I couldn't be able to solve the problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you also know that if $A$ and $B$ are each diagonalizable and satisfy $AB = BA$, then they are simultaneously diagonalizable?

Comment: No I didn't know that, then there is nothing to show :) thanks

Comment: Alternatively, there is a quick answer that uses the spectral theorem.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I dont know about spectral theorem. I mean we didn't learn it yet:)

Comment: How do you know that every normal matrix is diagonalizable, then?

Comment: There is a theorem about that and the proof does not include anything more than, cayley hamilton and a lemma saying $A^r=0 \implies A=0$.

Comment: Do you know that we can choose the $P$ that diagonalizes $A$ to be unitary?